# How can I add a load spinner to my React components, if I'm rendering them on node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("todo",{}); // todo is my main component
})
```

I would like to send the client a loader until all components are ready to be shown on the client side. How would you guys implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader would have to be on the client side because the page can't be reloaded by the server. In your client side code, render a top level component that wraps your other components and displays them instead of the spinner when they're ready.

Comment: Hey nick, thanks for your answer. Do you know how I could transfer a React.js component from my node.js to my client? This would allow me to implement a loader. -> rendering loader -> fetching component -> rendering component. :/! Thanks a lot

Comment: There's [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) which supports node.js. You could server render some code that shows a spinner and then continue rendering the component on the client, changing state when data is hydrated. However it would probably be simpler to just skip the server render and do it in JS since loaders aren't useful for SEO and your app would require JS anyway.

Comment: Thanks :)! Worked fine